STM32F4 SDIO keeps failing CRC check
I'm trying to get 4-bit SDIO with FATFS working on an NUCLEOF411RE board and so far, it isn't going well. Here's my current code to start.
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "fatfs.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SD_HandleTypeDef hsd;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_sdio_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_sdio_tx;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
FRESULT res; /* FatFs function common result code */
uint32_t byteswritten, bytesread; /* File write/read counts */
uint8_t wtext[] = "STM32 FATFS works great!"; /* File write buffer */
uint8_t rtext[_MAX_SS];/* File read buffer */
char res_check[32] = "";
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/**
 * @brief  Detects if SD card is correctly plugged in the memory slot or not.
 * @param  None
 * @retval Returns if SD is detected or not
 */
uint8_t BSP_SD_IsDetected(void){
  __IO uint8_t status = SD_PRESENT;

  if (BSP_PlatformIsDetected() != 0x0)
  {
    status = SD_NOT_PRESENT;
  }

  return status;
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_SDIO_SD_Init();
  BSP_SD_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  res = f_mount(&SDFatFS, (TCHAR const*)SDPath, 0);
  sprintf(res_check, "res = %d\r\n", res);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) res_check, sizeof(res_check), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  if(res != FR_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    else
    {
        res = f_mkfs((TCHAR const*)SDPath, FM_ANY, 0, rtext, sizeof(rtext));
        sprintf(res_check, "res = %d\r\n", res);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *) res_check, sizeof(res_check), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        if(res != FR_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
        else
        {
            res = f_open(&SDFile, "STM32.TXT", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE);
            //Open file for writing (Create)
            if(res != FR_OK)
            {
                Error_Handler();
            }
            else
            {

                //Write to the text file
                res = f_write(&SDFile, wtext, strlen((char *)wtext), (void *)&byteswritten);
                if((byteswritten == 0) || (res != FR_OK))
                {
                    Error_Handler();
                }
                else
                {

                    f_close(&SDFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  res = f_mount(&SDFatFS, (TCHAR const*)NULL, 0);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 72;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief SDIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SDIO_SD_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 1 */
  hsd.Instance = SDIO;
  hsd.Init.ClockEdge = SDIO_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;
  hsd.Init.ClockBypass = SDIO_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDIO_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_1B;
  hsd.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDIO_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;
  hsd.Init.ClockDiv = 255;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SDIO_Init 2 */
  //hsd.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_4B;
  /* USER CODE END SDIO_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream3_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Stream6_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream6_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream6_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD2_GPIO_Port, LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LD2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

So, the problem occurs in the length of calls/interrupts occurring in res = f_mkfs((TCHAR const*)SDPath, FM_ANY, 0, rtext, sizeof(rtext));
It gets to line 531 of sd_diskio.c (while((WriteStatus == 0) && ((HAL_GetTick() - timeout) < SD_TIMEOUT))), indicating that WriteStatus isn't being updated. So, I trawled around to see where that would get updated, which is declared in sd_diskio.c on line 485, and called by HAL_SD_TxCpltCallback, declared in bsp_driver_sd.c on line 249.
I laid down some breakpoints to try and find where it was getting hung up, but the instead I got stopped in stm32f4xx_hal_sd.c, in a __weak interrupt I didn't have a breakpoint in: __weak void HAL_SD_ErrorCallback at line 1776. From there at least, I was able to backtrack through the debugger to find the chain that eventually got me to that function, starting with the SDIO_IRQHAndler. 
From there, I was able to just keep clicking "step into" to get as deep into the problem as I possibly could, and the first thing I found that indicated a problem was in HAL_SD_IRQHandler, at line 1622;
   if(__HAL_SD_GET_FLAG(hsd, SDIO_FLAG_DCRCFAIL) != RESET) { hsd->ErrorCode |= HAL_SD_ERROR_DATA_CRC_FAIL; }
I'm still not 100% sure what's causing this. According to the brief for __HAL_SD_GET_FLAG(), the SDIO_FLAG_DCRCFAIL means "Data block sent/received (CRC check failed)" but I can't find any sign that anything was ever sent. Does anyone know what might be happening?
